# Compare dates with PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

Here is my question:

I have 2 datetime fields with the following values.

```
- n_date = '2015-11-06 00:00:00.000'
- ArrivalDate = '2015-11-06 01:00:00.000'
```

I want to compare only the date part of these fields so that the following:

```
if ($n_date!=$v[ArrivalDate]
{
do something ...
}
```

Does not do something

thx in advance!

Comment: Did you try and google? I know you're not the first one who wants to compare dates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` for this,

```
if((date("Y-m-d",strtotime($n_date))) == (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($ArrivalDate)))) {
      // both dtae are equal
} else {
      // both date are not equal
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, the OP wants to compare only the date part (i.e. ignoring the time portion).

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it...